# Дописать текст в файл с новой строки node.js

Tags: node.js, файлы

Как дописать некий текст в с новой строки в текстовом файле? Используется стандартный модуль `fs`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вы можете воспользоваться, например, функцией **fs.appendFileSync**. Передав данные для записи в файл и добавив в начало данных символ перевода строки. Вот так:

```
fs.appendFileSync('file.txt', `\n${data_to_append}`);
```

здесь **data_to_append** - это переменная, содержащая данные для добавления.
Однако символ перевода строки разный на разных платформах. Поэтому можно немного расширить пример, добавив выбор символа перевода строки в зависимости от платформы (windows или linux):

```
const newLineChar = process.platform === 'win32' ? '\r\n' : '\n';
fs.appendFileSync('file.txt', `${newLineChar}${data_to_append}`);
```

Правка от Qwertiy: для определения символа перевода строки в зависимости от платформы есть константа в пакете os. Поэтому символ перевода строки можно получить так:

```
require('os').EOL
```

Comment: `require('os').EOL`

Comment: Спасибо, поправил.